# Highcharts categories from data array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

I'm trying to pull data from a mysql table and set it as the x-axis categories but I don't quite understand how.

Basically, I have Job numbers in a table, and I want to pull those and make them the categories on the x-axis, eventually when a column is clicked for a specific job, it'll drill down for more columns (which add up to the total percentage of the job number).

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do, it works with the column data when using an array there but not with the categories so it wouldn't work this way.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoJqA

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if the question is "how can i do this with php/mysql" or "how can i define column names in highcharts". i'll try to answer the latter.
try this code to show custom column names instead of 1,2,3,...:

```
$(function () { 
    var data = {"name":"Percentage","data":[50,28,150,125,34,75]};
    var categories = [5600, 5700,5800,5900,6000,6100];
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Job Budget Report'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: categories
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: '% Budget hrs'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
             }]
        },
        series: [data]
    });
});
```

Comment: Well its both, I've got a drill down highcharts column graph. I got the Job Numbers to display using a query and <?php echo join($jobNum, ',') ?> on the initial columns thanks to everyones help here (gave me a better understanding) however, the second level of the drill down is giving me some trouble. Do you think you could help me on how to do this? Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/98Fuq/4/

Comment: fiddle seems to work fine, when I click on the columns the detail columns are coming up. what seems to be the problem?

Comment: There is no problem with that. But as you can see the data is hard coded so I was wondering if you knew a good solution to pull data from my table for each job. Lets take surfacing for example, when I pull data for this, every single surfacing hours are posted regardless of which job is clicked. Maybe I should create a new question.

Comment: Another question would be better. don't forget to include your database scheme to the question, so people can answer in your own structure.

Comment: Here's my new question if you want to take a look.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556778/highcharts-pulling-data-from-database-table

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Highcharts but if it does not have an interface to directly access a database I think all you would need to do is pull the data from the mySQL query and put it in an array that would be used by Highcharts.

Maybe something like:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$countsPerJob = array();
$res = $mysqli->query( "SELECT jobNumber FROM JobTable" );
while( ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) ) {
    if( isset( $countsPerJob[$row['jobNumber'] ) ) {
        ++$countsPerJob[$row['jobNumber']];
    } else {
        $countsPerJob[$row['jobNumber']] = 1;
    }
}
```

Now `$countsPerJob` has all the information from the database table.
You can then use the keys from `$countsPerJob` for the categories and the value for each 
entry in the array for the column height.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have more data than categories ? (You have 6 data points and 3 categories).

However, I think you need to supply an array to the categories, but you are supplying an object. You can change your code to:

```
$(function () { 
    var data = {"name":"Percentage","data":[50,28,150,125,34,75]};
    var categories = [5600, 5700,5800];
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Job Budget Report'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: categories
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: '% Budget hrs'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
             }]
        },
        series: [data]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

'categories' is just a simple array.  You would specify it as

```
var categories = [5600, 5700,5800];
```

And then in the chart:

```
xAxis: {
  categories: categories
}
```

(or, of course, you could just populate them directly in the chart)

However, as noted elsewhere, you have 3 categories and 6 data points, so your last 3 data points will have categories of '3', '4', and '5' as is.

If the chart is supposed to be a grouped chart, you'll need to set your data up differently.
If not, you'll need to supply more category titles.